# Android coordinater layout contain Multiple View is not Collapsing

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Linear layout In the collapsing toolbar layout is not collapsing. And views are overlaping. Also, view inside the Tab layout(fragments) also not scrolling.

I want to stick the tabs. Views in the tabs have to scroll.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/htab_maincontent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/htab_appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/htab_collapse_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

        <!--<ImageView-->
            <!--android:id="@+id/htab_header"-->
            <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:background="@drawable/header"-->
            <!--android:fitsSystemWindows="true"-->
            <!--android:scaleType="centerCrop"-->
            <!--app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />-->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/realtive1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
                android:layout_margin="20dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
                    android:src="@drawable/share" />

                <com.example.imageround.RoundedImageView
                    android:id="@+id/user_profile_image"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/parent_profile" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/user_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/user_profile_image"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:text="Saurabh Kumar" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/edit_btn" />

            </RelativeLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/realtive1"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/followers_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/login_back"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="FOLLOWERS" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/following_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/login_back"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="FOLLOWING" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fav_button"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/login_backb"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="FAV" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/line_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:background="@color/white"></View>

        </LinearLayout>



        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/htab_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:titleMarginTop="13dp" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/htab_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/htab_viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```